# Converting Raster to Polygon in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, convert, vectorization

I've prepared my Shapefile in ArcMap 10.7.1 by Raster to Polygon. When I am opening this shapefile in ArcMap its showing a rectangular polygon around the shapefile like this:

[image]

When I select this rectangular shapefile from Open attribute table, its select all other part of shapefile. I just want to remove the boundary level shapefile, so that, I able to calculate area of shapefile.

**Output looks like this**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to use [Multipart To Singlepart](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) tool to explode all the multipart polygon shapefile into single polygons, then you can select the unwanted polygon from the output shapefile, and delete.

Another approach is to edit the shapefile from the Editor toolbar. Go to start editing, select all polygon shapefile, go to Advance editing, and select [Explode](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/separating-a-multipart-feature.htm). This will do in-place editing of the shapefile and create single polygons. Finally, select the unwanted polygon and delete.

Comment: That looks like the polygons I would derive from arcpy.sa.IsNull on a count raster with no nodata value to discern LiDAR coverage. Polygons generated by raster to polygon aren't multipart unless the OP has dissolved at some stage. In this case I would suggest to clip the polygons with a minimum bounding geometry of the 2nd picture feature class to trim the excess or the IsNull of the original raster that generated the polygons.. it's not clear what the user has to suggest a method that suits their data.

Comment: @MichaelStimson yes I agree. After careful looking at the first image, it seem the outer polygon and some of the small polygons inside the assumed boundary have the same pixel values. My suggestion in this case is to give the big rectangle, which is normally the black or the null data in the raster data, a different pixel value. But currently it has same pixel value with some other pixels inside his study area.

Comment: @ahmadhanb dear, how can I change back ground values different from other polygons. You suggest me to set back ground values as null and then try raster to polygon?

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem Without seeing your original raster data how it looks like, it is difficult to give a concrete answer. However, if the background is not null already, then try to set it to null, and try again. If it did not work, then you can use `Con()` expression to give the background a new value different from any other pixel value existing in your raster data. Then, you will be able to select the background polygon and delete it when you convert the raster data to vector because the polygon attribute value is unique.

Comment: It's not easy to separate the NoData from legitimate data values if the value is in range, I would say that your NoData is probably 0 and so is the bulk of the raster. Go back to your original image and see if there was a different NoData value in that raster that wasn't in the range of legitimate values. If that doesn't work you can try minimum bounding geometry https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003q000000 with the geometry_type of CONVEX_HULL to get fairly close then manually rectify the worst deviations.

Comment: How can I share my raster to this plate form? Any method